# Como relacionar um model em outro model no Django 2

Tags: python-3.x, django

Estou fazendo um sistema no qual preciso mostrar dados que estão cadastrados em outro Model, que no caso é o campo Categoria que está na Model Itens e ao mostrá-las, o usuário selecionaria uma delas e o sistema mostraria os dados que estão somente vinculados à categoria selecionada.

Ex.:

Cadastro de armário

Nome:

Descrição:

Categorias: Calçados| Calças| Blusas| * Selecionei Blusas

Itens: Aqui o sistema mostra somente os itens da categoria Blusas com a opção de selecionar o item

Armário: Conterá os itens selecionados.

---

**itens\models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Categoria(models.Model):
    name_categoria = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_categoria

class Cor(models.Model):
    cor_item = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cor_item

class ItenManager(models.Manager):
    def search(self, query):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(
            models.Q(name__icontains=query) | \
            models.Q(cor__icontains=query)
        )

class Itens(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nome:', max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField('Atalho:')
    categoria = models.ForeignKey('Categoria',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cor = models.ForeignKey('Cor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='itens_imagens', verbose_name='Imagem:', null=True, blank=True
    )
    objects = ItenManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('itens:details', (), {'slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Item'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Itens'
        ordering = ['name']
```

---

**armario\models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Armario(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField('Nome',max_length=50, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField('Atalho')
    descricao = models.CharField('Descrição',max_length=100, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateField('Criado em', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField('Atualizado em',auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Armário'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Armários'
        ordering = ['name']
```

Comment: Você pode usar javascript (ajax) para enviar uma requisição para a url do django quando o usuário selecionar a categoria.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, o relacionamento entre os modelos já está feito aí - não tem muito o que mexer nesse lado.

Agora é pensar como você vai apresentar essas informações. Se você está desenvolvendo uma aplicação WEB com páginas estáticas: suas views retornam templates renderizados, que são preenchidos com variáveis do Python, a única coisa que você precisa a mais (além de pensar bem suas views e templates), é colocar a opção `related_name` no modelo `Itens`. (aliás, 'itens' pode não ser um bom nome - se não achar nada melhor, pelo menos é melhor deixar no singular `Item` - todas as outras classes são no singular, não é?)

Mas então, dentro de itens, você declara as categorias assim:

```
categoria = models.ForeignKey('Categoria', related_name='itens', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Fazendo isso, dentro de objetos da classe `Categoria` você pode usar o atributo `itens` que devolve uma sequência de todos os itens daquela categoria - isso pode ser usado direto no template, com o `for`:

```
<p> Categoria {{ categoria.name_categoria }} :<p>
<ul>
  {% for item in categoria.items %}
    <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Isso funciona por que quando o django preenceh os dados de um template, isso ainda é feito por código Python rodando no servidor, que tem acesso a todas as variáveis e ao banco de dados.

Agora, se sua aplicação carrega dados dinâmicamente, com ajax, ou usando frameworks como angular, react, etc...  - nesse caso você vai ter views que retornam os dados dos objetos serializados como JSON.

Nesse caso, para economizar chamadas, pode ser interessante embutir alguns dos dados dos seus itens quando a pessoa solicitar uma categoria - isso pode ser feito manualmente no código da view (você cria um dicionário em Python que vai adicionar todos os dados que vão ser passados para o front-end, nesse dicionário inclui uma chave `itens`, e uma lista com os nomes e links para os itens, por exemplo),

from django.http import JsonResponse

```
def categorias_view(request):
    resposta = []
    for categoria in models.Categoria.objects.all():
        dados_categoria = {}
        dados_categoria['nome'] = categoria.categoria_name
        dados_categoria['itens'] = [item.name for item in categoria.items]
        resposta.append(dados_categoria)
    return JsonResponse(resposta)
```

A outra opção no caso de uma app web com chamadas dinâmicas, é dar mais um passo e vê sobre o "Django rest framework"  (DRF) - que permite que você use bem pouco ou nenhum código pra cirar esssas views que renderizam os dados dos objetos como JSON. Nesse caso, você vai criar classes associadas a cada modelo que são chamadas de ["serializers"](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/). O framework dá uma porção de atalhos para você embutir os dados relacionados desejados dentro do seu JSON sem precisar ficar fazendo isso manualmente.
O uso do DRF faz muitas mágicas, que podem economizar muita digitação em sistemas grandes - mas se você tem poucos objetos, e está aprendendo, eu recomendaria fazer as views retornando json manualmente, até você entender legal o que está fazendo, e o que daria para automatizar, e aí passar para o DRF - senão ele vai ficar parecendo um monte de burocracia a mais, e no final faz uma mágica e "dá certo".